IGBT with double emitter
I have this circuit in the photo that has two transistors that appear to be IGBT, but they have two complementary emitters, and apparently the floating collector. What component is this, I tried to find it through the code but I found another completely different one, which is a MOSFET.


That's a standard (if perhaps less common today?) IGBT symbol.  The collector part implies the emitter of the internal PNP structure; gate and dashed base/body, the MOSFET structure; and the, I think, substrate and emitter, the, well, substrate and emitter.  Not sure offhand how well this implies the parasitic NPN part, or JFET part, but it at least hints at the important aspects.
Understanding of semiconductor symbology is sadly sorely lacking these days; call me an old fogey but I strongly object to the common convention of making MOSFETs look like BJTs.  It's not just an aesthetic or semantic gripe, though: I've seen real, objective mistakes, written into datasheets, by major manufacturers.  Easily avoided if the drafters simply knew what the MOSFET symbol already means.
(So, I appreciate the opportunity to expound on the topic and spread at least a tiny bit of awareness of this fact.)
To be clear: a straight line segment usually means base or substrate (going back far enough (point-contact, alloy junction), these were the same thing); arrow, a junction (pointing from P to N); line touching a region, an ohmic (right angled, FET) or PN (diagonal line, BJT collector) junction.  'S' ends are added for a (rectifying) schottky junction.  Substrate can be continuous to indicate depletion mode (default conducting), or dashed to indicate enhancement mode (default insulating).
Thus, the traditional MOSFET symbol shows a diode junction (middle substrate connection to channel), the body diode; and the IGBT above, at least implies collector and emitter junctions, and, the floating collector is kind of weird, but at least in the sense of "there's a PNP collector down here", it works to convey that.
